# Search criteria with Result and Count in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, pagination, hibernate-criteria

I have search criteria with multiple field in the table. Is it possible to use same hibernate criteria object to get Result (with setFirstResult and setMaxResult) and count for Pagination? I mean the result set for my search criteria with pagination and the total number of result for that specific search criteria.

Steps:

1. Create criteria with my search parameter.
2. Set first and max result parameter.
3. Create row count projection. (This should return total count of my search parameter, not within my first and max result parameter).
4. Get current page result set.
5. Get total count for search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pagination looks like this

```
public List<YourEntity> findDeviceTransactions(Integer id) {
    return session.createCriteria(YourEntity.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)) // add more Restrictions if you want
            .setFirstResult(page)
            .setMaxResults(10) //this can be a constant in your properties
            .list();
```

}

the count looks like

```
 public int countYourEntityForPagination(Integer id) {
     return ((Number) session.createCriteria(YourEntity.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)) // add more Restrictions if you want
            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
            .uniqueResult()).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Yes, i did exactly same as of now. I am looking if it is possible to use same Criteria to get both.